# Linker error in MDI Qt application: undefined reference to qInitResources_mdi()

Tags: c++, qt, mdi

I am trying to convert my Qt application to MDI (Multiple Document Interface).

I built the [mdi example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-mdi.html) and everything works smoothly.

Now, following the example, I modified my code, adding this line at the beginning of main():

```
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(mdi);
```

I also `#include <QApplication>` and `<QtGui>`.

I get this linker error:
`main.cpp:24: undefined reference to 'qInitResources_mdi()'`

Why is that line accepted in the example and not in my code? I include the same headers, and the makefiles seem not to be the reason.

Platform:  Windows 7, MinGW, Qt 4.8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I thought that `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(mdi)` was needed to initialize the application in Multiple Document Interface mode. Instead it just loads a set of files (icons in this case) that were missing from my project.

Removing that line fixed the problem.